How to generate a single static page by path during Next.js build?
I'm working on a Next.js project and I'd like to optimize the build process by generating only a single static page based on its path, instead of rebuilding the entire application.
For example, if I have a page located at /pages/blog/[slug].js, I want to build only the page for a specific slug, like /blog/my-article, without affecting other pages.
Is there a way to achieve this with Next.js, either using a specific build command, custom script, or configuration?
